# Sqoop Import "--where" flag

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I tried to import specific rows from a MySQL table to HDFS using sqoop --where flag but the results were not as expected.

**Command:**

```
sqoop import \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://XXXX.YYYY/XXXX/retail_db" \
  --username XXXX \
  --password XXXX \
  --query "select * from departments where \$CONDITIONS \
  --where "department_id < 5" \
  --target-dir /XXX/YYY/departments \
  --split-by department_id
```

**MySQL table rows:**

```
department_id  department_name
-------------  ---------------
2              Fitness
3              Footwear
4              Apparel
5              Golf
6              Outdoors
7              Fanshop
8000           Test
```

After the command is run, the expected output should ideally be the first 3 rows with department_ids 2,3 and 4 but instead all rows are imported. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop does not know a WHERE flag.

Change your query to

```
  --query "select * from departments where \$CONDITIONS \
        department_id < 5 \
        AND \$CONDITIONS" \
```

and remove the line

```
--where "department_id < 5" \
```

The query should work fine.